# Turn a non prog-mode derived major-mode into a prog-mode derived major-mode

Tags: hooks, major-mode, prog-mode, erlang-mode

erlang-mode is not a derived prog-mode.

Is there any way to make it part of the prog-mode-hook ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you have to do is add `(run-hooks 'prog-mode-hook)` to `erlang-mode-hook`:

```
(add-hook 'erlang-mode-hook
          (lambda () (run-hooks 'prog-mode-hook)))
```

You should place this after anything else you add to `erlang-mode-hook` to make sure `prog-mode-hook` gets called *before* anything else.  That way `erlang-mode` can clobber any settings in `prog-mode` that it doesn't like.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand when it is better to hook the lambda. My intuition would say "as the very first function hooked to erlang-mode-hook" but your remark seems to say the opposite so I'm confused.

Comment: `add-hook` adds the function to the *beginning* of the hook (there is an optional third argument that will cause it to append instead).  So by adding `prog-mode-hook` last, it will become the first thing in the hook. I agree that this seems backwards, but it is what it is.

Comment: The `prog-mode` body will not run with this approach. A proper derived mode will run that before the `erlang-mode` body (which is before `change-major-mode-after-body-hook` runs, which is before the mode hooks run).

Answer (score 5):

In addition to answers given by @erikstokes and @Abbrev, you might want to add the following:

```
(put 'erlang-mode 'derived-mode-parent 'prog-mode)
```

It ensures that `(derived-mode-p 'prog-mode)` returns `t` for Erlang mode. This is useful since there are a number of utilities that are enabled for all modes that inherit from Prog mode.

However, a more permanent solution would be to lobby to the Erlang team to replace the old definition of `erlang-mode` with the following, more modern version (and drop some of the stuff this provides for free):

```
(if (fboundp 'prog-mode)
    (defmacro erlang-define-derived-mode (mode &rest args)
      `(define-derived-mode ,mode prog-mode ,@args))
  (defmacro erlang-define-derived-mode (mode &rest args)
    `(define-derived-mode ,mode nil ,@args)))

(erlang-define-derived-mode erlang-mode "Erlang"
  ...)
```

(Should someone decide to lobby for this, you can say "Anders Lindgren, the author of Erlang mode, suggested this.")

Answer (score 4):

`erlang-mode` probably doesn't inherit `prog-mode-abbrev-table` correctly, so any abbrevs you create for prog-mode won't work. Fix like so:

```
(eval-after-load erlang-mode
  (abbrev-table-put erlang-abbrev-table
                    :parents (list prog-mode-abbrev-table)))
```

This bug is shared by `python-mode` and `lisp-mode`, and they ship with Emacs!